# laravel migration showing old error after removing all migrations and DB?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

I have configured Laravel database config file to use postgres DB.
First of all when I tried to run migration, I got error like

> [PDOException]
>
> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "sales_default_calculations" does not exist
>      LINE 1: select "id" from "sales_default_calculations" where "status"...

I moved all my migrations from `database\migrations` folder to `database\migrations_bak` and dropped the Database and created new one. I even created new Database with different name than before. However, I get same above error, when I run `php artisan migrate`. Even though migration files and DB is cleared it's showing same old error message. What may have caused this anomaly? Please someone help.

Comment: It seems like you are seeding rather creating...!

Comment: @BasheerAhmed how does `php artisan migrate` command seed ?

Comment: Could you paste the `migration`..

Comment: @BasheerAhmed I have removed all migration file and even created fresh new Database and still `php artisan migrate` throws mentioned error,for empty database and no migration file,it still shows previous error.Is there some caching mechanism causing this error?

Comment: Ah you need  `php artisan config:cache` If you have changed the database name..

Comment: when you work with migrations in dev mode and you have made a lot of changes the best practice is to run these commands before migrating: `php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2):

When you make manual changes to `database/migrations` folder, you have to run the command `composer dump-autoload` to make sure the classes are reloaded.

Comment: also, since some tables have migrated already, you should have first ran the artisan migrate rollback command. modify your migration files and re-run the migration